# ios PWA(add to home screen) is not asking for Camera permission in Angular for video tag

Tags: ios, angular, safari, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

I have created PWA using angular in which I am using `zxing-ngx-scanner` library, which library for barcode scan. In ios browsers(Safari, Chrome and Firefox) and on Android it's asking for camera permissions and it's working fine, but if I add my site to homescreen(in ios), then it's not asking me for the camera permissions.

- I have hosted my site on HTTPS
- All PWA functionality working fine
- I am using  tag for the barcode scan

Please let me know if anyone has any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is fixed only for the iOs version 13.4 or later, the iOs version prior to this doesn't have permissions from Apple. Devices such as iPods or old iPhones might not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade to iOS 13.4 and try again. The fix that Apple provided may work now.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=185448#c88

Comment: Thanks, @Johannes for your response, it's working now